# Mock require(ed) service

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I'm trying to mock a service used by my function using sinon, but I can't find a way to *inject* the mock into my function.

The service is acquired using `require`

My function is like this:

```
// something.js
const service = require('./service');
module.exports = {
    // do something using a service
    doSomething: function (options) {
        let results = [];
        return service.foo(option.param)
        // and return the value adding some logic
        .then(function(resultFromService){
            // want to test this flag
            if ( options.someFlag ) {
                results = resultFromService;
            }
        })
        .then(function(){
            /// more existing code here
            return results;
         });
    } 
}
```

I'm trying to mock `service.foo` like this:

```
const something = require('../../something.js');
const sinon = require('sinon');  
...
it('should doSomething by calling foo in the service', function(done) {

     ///I'm getting this error here: Error: Trying to stub property 'foo' of undefined
     sinon.stub( something.service , 'foo' )
     .returns(when(function() {
         return ['bar', 'baz'];
     }));


     let promise = something.doSomething({param:'for service', someFlag:true});
});
```

And then check if my `doSomething` method is indeed executing the logic it is supposed to execute.

Q. How do I inject a mock service and/or a mock function for that service that is defined as a *private* closure scoped variable in my `something` function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to require `service` in your test and stub it directly.

```
let service = require('../../service.js');
sinon.stub(service, 'foo' )
.returns(when(function() {
         return ['bar', 'baz'];
}));
```

Comment: would `doSomething` use that now? ( trying )

Comment: Yes it should use the mocked object that is injected.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using [`mock-require`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require)

```
const mockRequire = require('mock-require');

it('do something', function(){
   mockRequire('./service', { 
      foo: function(p){
         return [];
      }
   });
   let something = require('./something.js); 
   // Now when it requires the service, it gets the mock instead
    something.doSomething({flag:true, param:'a'});
    assert. etc. etc
}));
```